# Exporting several services using Service Component Runtime

Tags: osgi, apache-felix, whiteboard

For example i have component exporting simple web-service:

```
@Component(
 property = ["osgi.jaxrs.resource=true"],
 configurationPid = ["some.file.config"]
)
@Path("/service")
open class Service {

 @GET
 @Produces("text/plain")
 @Path("/getData")
 fun getData(): Response = Response.ok("Some data").build()

 @POST
 @Consumes("text/plain")
 @Path("/setData")
 fun registered(inputData: String): Response = Response.ok().build()
}
```

Is creating another component only way to publish another service ? Can i do this somehow using single component ?

Comment: In what cases do you want to create different services like the one above? Depending on configuration?

Comment: Without any choosing, for example two different web-services using http whiteboard with only one Component in my project. Is it possible ? Or only one ws per Component ?